# Swift - Speed Search on list of words

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swiftui, combine

I have a textfield in SwiftUI  where the user inputs a word.  I capture the characters entered using Combine and want to search a list of word and list words in which the characters are found.
Eg user inputs d - list shows dan das dat den dev die din div
user inputs de - list shows den dev
user inputs dev - list shows dev

```
.onReceive(Just(textSearch.text)) { 
newString in if self.usedWords.contains(newString) {
 self.mySearch(searchWord: newString) } }
```

mySearch func is only called when there is a complete match of newString in an element of usedWords ... I need the partial matched

The last use-case works with string.contains("dev"), but does not work with string.contains("de").  Clearly contains cannot do the job of matching a substring and returning all that contains that substring.  Is there another swift utility that I could use ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you please add code which you have tried so far? @user3238267

Comment: Not readable from comments, Can you add your full code?

Comment: included in original question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is related to how you search. I think this is the problematic bit:

```
self.usedWords.contains(newString)
```

`self.usedWords` sounds like it's an array of strings: `[String]`

So for example `["one", "two", "three"]`. By calling `self.usedWords.contains(newString)` you check whether `usedWords` contains a string that equals `newString`. Not whether `usedWords` contains strings that contain `newString` as a substring. To find all words that have `newString` as its substring you should probably `filter` over `usedWords`:

```
let matches = self.usedWords.filter { word in 
  return word.contains(newString)
}
```

That would give you an array of all entries in `usedWords` that contain `newString` as a substring.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    .onReceive(Just(textSearch.text)) { newString in
            if newString.isEmpty { return }
            let result = self.usedWords.filter { $0.hasPrefix(newString) }
            result.forEach { tx in
                self.mySearch(searchWord: tx)
            }
    }
```